# `dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType` but obtain non-nearest ancestor?

Tags: flutter, dart

Consider the following case:

```
MyInheritedWidget(
  identity: "a",
  child: MyInheritedWidget(
    identity: "b",
    child: MyChildWidget(),
  ),
)
```

Inside `MyChildWidget`, I can use `context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<MyInheritedWiget>()` to get the *nearest* instance of `MyInheritedWiget` in my ancestors. Namely, the `b` in this case. However, I hope there exist an approach such that I can depend on the *non-nearest* one, `a` in this case.

For example, hope such API exists:

```
context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<MyInheritedWiget>((widget) => widget.identity == 'a')
```

Or such API may also be OK:

```
context.findAllInheritedWidgetsOfExactType<MyInheritedWiget>().where((widget) => widget.identity == 'a')
```

And so on. But I cannot find an appropriate API like this...

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to *depend* on the found ancestor widget, i.e. to be notified when the ancestor changes, use this approach:

1. Find desired ancestor consequentially calling `getElementForInheritedWidgetOfExactType`
2. Call `dependOnInheritedElement` for the found element and use returned value

```dart
extension BuildContextX on BuildContext {
  Iterable<InheritedElement> getElementsForInheritedWidgetsOfExactType<
      T extends InheritedWidget>() sync* {
    final element = getElementForInheritedWidgetOfExactType<T>();
    if (element != null) {
      yield element;

      Element? parent;
      element.visitAncestorElements((element) {
        parent = element;
        return false;
      });

      if (parent != null) {
        yield* parent!.getElementsForInheritedWidgetsOfExactType<T>();
      }
    }
  }

  T? dependOnSpecificInheritedWidgetOfExactType<T extends InheritedWidget>(
    bool Function(T) test,
  ) {
    final element = getElementsForInheritedWidgetsOfExactType<T>()
        .where((element) => test(element.widget as T))
        .firstOrNull;
    if (element == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return dependOnInheritedElement(element) as T;
  }
}
```

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String identity;

  ...

  static _MyWidget dependOnSpecific(
    BuildContext context, {
    required String identity,
  }) {
    return context.dependOnSpecificInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_MyWidget>(
      (widget) => widget.identity == identity,
    )!;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _MyWidget(
      identity: identity,
      child: ...,
    );
  }
}

class _MyWidget extends InheritedWidget {
  ...
}
```

Use it like this:

```dart
MyWidget.dependOnSpecific(context, identity: 'x')
```

Full example: https://dartpad.dev/?id=c311ca15d54dd905660fe9e2b1c8c337

Answer (score 1):

Each `Element` holds `HashMap<Type, InheritedElement>`. That's why we have quick access to inherited ancestors by type. But this approach limits us to one accessible widget of given type.

Another approach is iterating parents' elements until we find one that we need. This approach is implemented in `findAncestorStateOfType` and `findRootAncestorStateOfType` and used e.g by `Navigator.of` and `ScaffoldState.of`. Note that it's O(N). We can use it to find an ancestor with given property:

```dart
extension BuildContextX on BuildContext {
  Iterable<T> findAncestorStatesOfType<T extends State>() sync* {
    final ancestor = findAncestorStateOfType<T>();
    if (ancestor != null) {
      yield ancestor;
      yield* ancestor.context.findAncestorStatesOfType<T>();
    }
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String identity;

  ...

  static MyWidgetState findWith(
    BuildContext context, {
    required String identity,
  }) {
    return context
        .findAncestorStatesOfType<MyWidgetState>()
        .firstWhere((state) => state.widget.identity == identity);
  }

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => MyWidgetState();
}

class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  ...
}
```

Use it like this:

```dart
MyWidget.findWith(context, identity: 'x')
```

Full example: https://dartpad.dev/?id=e66d474b5685f6a2c815040ffda0b027

Comment: If you don't need StatefulWidget, you can use findAncestorWidgetOfExactType in the same way

Comment: Also consider using some DI approaches, e.g. riverpod's provider families: https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/modifiers/family

Comment: Thank you! But I wonder how can I "dependOn" the found ancestor widget? In other words, be notified when that particular ancestor changes.